# Not able to autowire Spring Rest Template

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

Below is my rest template configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
            <beans:property name="readTimeout" value="600000" />
            <beans:property name="connectTimeout" value="600000" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean id="byteArrayMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <beans:property name="objectMapper">
                    <beans:ref bean="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:value>text/plain</beans:value>
                        <beans:value>application/json</beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>


        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

I am getting a NPE when i try to autowire and access the template in a class:

```
@Service
public class GitService {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void getTot(String url) {

        List<ResponseObject> eg = (List<ResponseObject>) restTemplate.getForObject(url,ResponseObject.class);
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/github] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.assignment.github.service.GitService.getTot(GitService.java:25)
```

Can someone please tell what's wrong here?

Comment: `@Autowired` cannot be null. If you are using component-scanning or annotation based configured your application would fail to start. If can only be `null` if you are creating a instance of `GitService` yourself. I.e. do `new GitService()`. Spring will not know about that instance and as such cannot inject dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Please add these tag

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

if you have not

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<Your_base_package"/>
```

into same configuration file.

Comment: Why would you need `<mvc:annotation-driven />`? That is for configured annotation driven web stuff and has nothing to do with autowiring...

Comment: This is my practice when ever i got this problem i do this. next time i will use only first one @M.Deinum

Comment: You won't need that if you already have `<context:component-scan />` that already implies `<context:annotation-config />`.